# Is there an rmarkdown equivalent to LaTex \cite{} and a manual bibliography?

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a \cite{}, \bibitem{} type function in Rmarkdown, where I can manually enter my citations and bib items in a reference section. Can't find anything.

Comment: Which output format(s) do you target?

Comment: I only have html available unfortunately

Comment: If you can live with the references being formatted via a CSL file, you could use a `references` field in the YAML header, c.f. https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations (and somewhere in the Rmarkdown docs).

Comment: [Are you sure you can't find anything?](https://www.google.com/search?q=rmarkdown+cite)